# In search view filter by related one2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I have inherited account.account model and added a move_ids One2many field related to account.move.line model:

```
class ViewSumasYSaldos(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.account"

    moves_ids = fields.One2many('account.move.line', 'account_id', string="Account moves")
```

So now I need, in a search view, filter by date field from moves_ids. Is there any way to do this?

I need something like this:

```
<search>
    <field string="Year" filter_domain="[('move_ids.date', '=', self]" />
</search>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found the solution and answer myself,

```
<field string="Year" name="year" filter_domain="[('moves_ids.date', '&gt;=', str(self) + '-01-01'), ('moves_ids.date', '&lt;=', str(self) + '-12-31')]" />
```

where 'self' is the year.